# Min using right indexing python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python. I am stuck on this simple task for quite a while, but can't seem to find an answer.

[image]

I have a `pandas` dataframe, all I am trying to do is take take a min of two columns but where one column is lagged

```
enter code x = {'A': pd.Series([1,3,6,5,3,2]),
'B': pd.Series([4,2,8,4,4,2])}                                               
 x1 = pd.DataFrame(x)
x1.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: np.min(x['A'].iloc[1],x['B'].iloc[0],axis=1))
```

This gives me error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

If the code works, the answer should be

```
c = [NaN,3,2,5,3,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to shift the values of the dataframe before calling min

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,3,6,5,3,2],
'B': [4,2,8,4,4,2]}) 
df.B= df.B.shift(+1)
df.min(axis=1, skipna=False)
```

that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need ?

```
np.minimum(x1.A.values,x1.B.shift().values)
Out[603]: array([nan,  3.,  2.,  5.,  3.,  2.])
```